# Casting, c programming

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I got confused in interpreting this line:

```
a = (char*) b;
```

while `a` and `b` are both declared to be of type `char*`.

Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: If they are both declared char * then above code is equivalent to a =b;

Comment: It would just ignore the cast.  Maybe `b` used to be something else in previous versions of the code, and they never removed the now unnecessary cast?

Comment: Whoever *wrote* it was probabliy quite confused, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

If they are of the same type, there is no need to use casting in the expression and it is the same as

```
a = b;
```

**Edit:** example casting with pointers

If you are using a *C++ compiler*, you need casting when calling [malloc](http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/dynamic_memmory_allocation/malloc.aspx) function otherwise you get an error message. This function returns a `void*` pointer and you need to explicitly cast it to its destination type as implicit conversion from `void*` has not been inherited from C.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, [noooo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393). The compiler does not need your help with the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the point, but some compiler versions still send a warning when the cast is not present.

Comment: If they *are* C compilers (not C++), then they are badly broken. No spreading of misinformation in favor of a braindead compiler without mention, please... -1 gone ;)